# Laravel Update, doesn't update (method patch)

Tags: laravel

With `dd($request))` I have feedback but it doesn't update the post.

**Controller**

```
public function update (Post $post, Request $request){

    $post->update($request->all());
    return redirect('/');
}
```

**View**

```
 {!! Form::model($post, array('method'=>'PATCH','url'=>'/posts/'. $post->id))  !!}
```

Comment: Make your table columns fillable in the model.

Comment: i have already protected $fillable = ['title', 'body'];

Comment: Any errors appeared while executing ?

Comment: Check if the route used map to that method. Also, do you get any error? Provide more info.

Comment: no, none errors

Comment: if i use dd(($request))  in my update function it display my new data